# How to Define order of testcase files execution in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Is there a way in Rspec by which I can specify the order of exection by giving file input?

I have a `.txt` file which contain list of files in ordered manner. I want Rspec to execute testing of files in order specified in `.txt` file.
I am using CAPYBARA with Rspec (USING_CAPYBARA=true rspec -r turnip/rspec -r turnip/capybara spec/features/../../.)

EDIT:

Whenever the features fails on my CI tool, I get the list of file names in sequence which was executed by my CI tool. When I simply run my failing test it works fine, but to debug such issue I need to run the test files in same sequence as the CI tool. So I think if Rspec doesn't provide a way to rerun the specs files in specific sequence I guess I need to write some script for it then

Comment: RSpec runs test in a random order for a reason. Why do you think it is better to run test in a fixed order? What problem to you try to solve?

Comment: Rspec also reports what seed it has used to randomize the order if you want to run tests in the same order again. You could write a small script in a suitable language that takes the file and executes rspec for each of them?

Comment: @spickermann @ ndn I am aware about why RSpec randomise the sequence. Please see my edited question for my requirement.

Comment: You may find rspec --bisect useful for fixing order dependant failures.

Comment: RSpec usually tells you which seed it used to randomize the order. Look for something like: `Randomized with seed 47311`. You can use that number to re-run specs in the same order: `spec spec --seed 47311`

Comment: @spickermann Thanks!!... just to clear it further... I know that `seed` remembers the order of test cases for single file. But does it also follow the order of File execution as well?

Comment: @Hardik: Yes, find details in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSpec tells you which `seed` it used to randomize the order. Look for something like:

```
Randomized with seed 47311.
```

You can use that number to re-run specs in the same order:

```
$ spec spec --seed 47311 # or --order rand:47311
```

> From the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order):
>   *Use the --order option to tell RSpec how **to order the files, groups, and
>   examples**. The available ordering schemes are defined and rand.*